# PHP Router Parameters

Tags: php, model-view-controller, router

I am looking for advice in passing parameters in my router's routes.
This is my router...

```
<?php namespace Framework;

class Router
{
    private array $routes = [];
    private Request $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    public function get(string $path, string|callable|array $callback): void
    {
        $this->routes['GET'][$path] = $callback;
    }

    public function post(string $path, string|callable|array $callback): void
    {
        $this->routes['POST'][$path] = $callback;
    }

    public function dispatch(): mixed
    {
        $method = $this->request->method();
        $path = $this->request->path();
        $callback = $this->routes[$method][$path];

        if(is_null($callback))
        {
            throw new Exception\NotFoundException;
        }

        if(is_string($callback))
        {
            return new View($callback);
        }

        if(is_array($callback))
        {
            $callback[0] = new $callback[0];
        }

        return call_user_func($callback);
    }
}
```

And my routes look like this...

```
return function (App $app)
{
    $app->get('/', [Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index']);
    $app->get('/about', [Controllers\HomeController::class, 'about']);
    $app->get('/contact', function() {
        var_dump(App::load()->request()->body());
    });

    $app->get('/blog', [Controllers\BlogController::class, 'index']);
    $app->get('/blog/{id}', [Controllers\BlogController::class, 'index']);
};
```

I want to be able to pass a parameter (for example on the last blog route). And I am sort of at a loss about how to go about it.

Comment: Want to add Laravel Routes to your project?

Comment: @Akbarali I am thinking about it. But I would prefer to create this one from scratch. To get a better idea about how it works.

Comment: This isn't a trivial task. You need to parse and digest every piece of the $request URI beyond the base URL, then match that up with the regex you are defining in your routes. Based on that information, you can then determine which parts are the URL and which parts are function parameters, like {id}. This is a little bit like reinventing the wheel, so I'd suggest checking out how other frameworks do this. CodeIgniter might be a good start as this is basically the same format (Laravel too I think?).